# Google Plus Id From Contacts List

Tags: android, google-plus

In (almost) every android phone from 4.0 we have a contact name "ME" that is connected to the Google Plus of the user.

I want to get the social id of the user using this contact.
I tried to read it from

```
ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI
```

and from

```
ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI
```

Without any luck..
Can someone give me a hand?

Thank you very much!